# React - Used Route(path ,exact, component) to render a component on a specified path but it will only render if I hit refresh once the path matches

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used `this.props.history.push("/register")` in the click handler function for my register button and it does work because when I click the button, the path in the address bar changes to `"/register"`. Then I used `<Route path="/register" exact={true} component={Register}></Route>` in `App.jsx` so that it renders my form which is in my Register component. My problem is that when I click my register button the path changes to `"/register"` but it will not render my Register component unless I hit refresh after the path has changed to `"/register"`. How do I get the Register component to render as soon as the path changes to `"/register"` (aka without having to hit refresh to get it to render)?

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, withRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../src/examples/Footer";
import SiteNav from "../src/examples/SiteNav";
import Jumbo from "../src/examples/Jumbo";
import Register from "../src/examples/Register";


import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <SiteNav {...this.props}>
        </SiteNav>
        <main role="main">
          <div className="container">
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Jumbo}></Route>
            <Route path="/register" exact={true} component={Register}></Route>
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer>
        </Footer>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

SiteNav Component

```
import React from "react";
import * as userService from "../services/userService";

class SiteNav extends React.Component {
  
  onLoginClicked = () => {
    console.log("onLoginClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/login");
  }

  onRegisterClicked = () => {
    console.log("onRegisterClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/register");
  }

  onLogoutClicked = () => {
    console.log("onLogoutClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/logout");
  }
    
  onHomeClicked = () => {
    console.log("onHomeClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  onFriendsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onFriendsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/friends");
  }

  onBlogsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onBlogsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/blogs");
  }

  onTechCoClicked = () => {
    console.log("onTechCoClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/techCo");
  }

  onJobsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onJobsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/jobs");
  }

  onEventsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onEventsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/events");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = {};
    userService.logIn(data)
    .then(this.onActionSuccess)
    .catch(this.onActionError);
  }

  onActionSuccess = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
   
  onActionError= (errResponse) => {
    console.warn(errResponse);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    let currentPath = this.props.location.pathname;
    let previousPath = prevProps.location.pathname;
    console.log({currentPath, previousPath});
  }

    render() {
        return(
            <header className="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
              <a
                href="/"
                className="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none"
              > 
                <img
                  src="https://pw.sabio.la/images/Sabio.png"
                  width="30"
                  height="30"
                  className="d-inline-block align-top"
                  alt="Sabio"
                />
              </a>

              <ul className="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="#"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-secondary link-button"
                    onClick={this.onHomeClicked}>
                    Home
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button" onClick={this.onFriendsClicked}>
                    Friends
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="#"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onBlogsClicked}>
                    Blogs
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="#"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onTechCoClicked}>
                    Tech Co.
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="#"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onJobsClicked}>
                    Jobs
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="#"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onEventsClicked}>
                    Events
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <form className="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3">
                <input
                  type="search"
                  className="form-control form-control-dark"
                  placeholder="Search..."
                  aria-label="Search"
                />
              </form>

              <div className="text-end">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light me-2" onClick={this.onLoginClicked}>
                  Login
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning me-2" onClick={this.onRegisterClicked}>
                  Register
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger me-2" onClick={this.onLogoutClicked}>
                  Logout
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        
        );
    }
}

export default SiteNav;
```

Register Component

```
import React from "react";


class Register extends React.Component {

    onSubmitClicked = () => {
        console.log("onSubmitClicked");
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
              <div className="container-fluid py-5">
                <h4>Register a user</h4>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputFirstName"></label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputLastName"></label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputLasttName" name="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputEmail"></label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword"></label>
                        <input type="new-password" className="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPasswordConfirm"></label>
                        <input type="new-password" className="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" name="inputPasswordConfirm" placeholder="Retype Password"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputAvatarUrl"></label>
                        <input type="url" className="form-control" id="inputAvatarUrl" name="inputAvatarUrl" placeholder="Avatar Url"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check m-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="checkBox" name="checkBox"></input>
                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="checkBox">
                            <b>
                                I agree to the <font color="blue">terms</font>
                            </b>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button id="register" type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onSubmitClicked}>Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Jumbo Component

```
import React from "react";

class Jumbo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
              <div className="container-fluid py-5">
                <h1 className="display-5 fw-bold">Hello, world!</h1>
                <p className="col-md-8 fs-4">
                  This is the homepage for the Starter Task.
                </p>
                <p>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                    Learn more &raquo;
                  </button>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Jumbo;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using `<Link>` from `react-router-dom`.
So all I had to do was use `<Link to="/">` for the Home link and `<Link to="/register">` for the Register button. Here are my changes:

SiteNav Component

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import * as userService from "../services/userService";

class SiteNav extends React.Component {
  
  onLoginClicked = () => {
    console.log("onLoginClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/login");
  }

  onRegisterClicked = () => {
    console.log("onRegisterClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/register");
  }

  onLogoutClicked = () => {
    console.log("onLogoutClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/logout");
  }
    
  onHomeClicked = () => {
    console.log("onHomeClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  onFriendsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onFriendsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/friends");
  }

  onBlogsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onBlogsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/blogs");
  }

  onTechCoClicked = () => {
    console.log("onTechCoClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/techCo");
  }

  onJobsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onJobsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/jobs");
  }

  onEventsClicked = () => {
    console.log("onEventsClicked was clicked");
    this.props.history.push("/events");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = {};
    userService.logIn(data)
    .then(this.onActionSuccess)
    .catch(this.onActionError);
  }

  onActionSuccess = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
   
  onActionError= (errResponse) => {
    console.warn(errResponse);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    let currentPath = this.props.location.pathname;
    let previousPath = prevProps.location.pathname;
    console.log({currentPath, previousPath});
  }

    render() {
        return(
            <header className="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
              <a
                href="/"
                className="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none"
              > 
                <img
                  src="https://pw.sabio.la/images/Sabio.png"
                  width="30"
                  height="30"
                  className="d-inline-block align-top me-2"
                  alt="Sabio"
                />
              </a>

              <ul className="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
                <li>
                  <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                    <button
                    href="#"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-secondary link-button"
                    onClick={this.onHomeClicked}>
                    Home
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                  href="/friends" 
                  className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button" 
                  onClick={this.onFriendsClicked}>
                    Friends
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="/blogs"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onBlogsClicked}>
                    Blogs
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="/techCo"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onTechCoClicked}>
                    Tech Co.
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="/jobs"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onJobsClicked}>
                    Jobs
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    href="/events"
                    className="nav-link px-2 text-white link-button"
                    onClick={this.onEventsClicked}>
                    Events
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <form className="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3">
                <input
                  type="search"
                  className="form-control form-control-dark"
                  placeholder="Search..."
                  aria-label="Search"
                />
              </form>

              <div className="text-end">
                <Link to="/register">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning me-2" onClick={this.onRegisterClicked}>Register</button>
                </Link>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light me-2" onClick={this.onLoginClicked}>
                  Login
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger me-2" onClick={this.onLogoutClicked}>
                  Logout
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        
        );
    }
}

export default SiteNav;
```